# Creating a PL/SQL procedure and anonymous block with different inputs

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

My DB structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BA3l.jpg

My question involves two parts

1. Write a stored procedure that can be used to find the number of cars and total amount of money a customer has spent on all cars they have bought. This procedure will be used in question 2, but it can be used in any circumstance to find the number of cars and the total amount spent by one or more customers. Only use parameters to pass/receive data. Do not use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to display data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cust_spent (
    cust_name      IN    car.custname%TYPE,
    name_output    OUT   car.custname%TYPE,
    num_output     OUT   car.carserial%TYPE,
    total_output   OUT   car.purchcost%TYPE
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        custname,
        COUNT(carserial) AS numcar,
        purchcost AS totalcost
    INTO name_output, num_output, total_output
    FROM
        car
    WHERE
        custname = cust_name
    GROUP BY
        custname, purchcost;

END;
```

As you can see this part requires the customer name as in input.

The second part

2. Write an anonymous block that would prompt the user to enter a city and uses the procedure created previously (in #1) to display the number of cars and the amount spent on cars for each customer from that city, and then display the total cars and total amount spent for all the customers from that city. You can use a cursor or a collection to store all the customers from the city and loop through and call the procedure within to display the number of cars and the money spent by the customers. Keep in mind that each city may have been stored in the database in different case spellings (for example OAKVILLE, oakville or Oakville are to be treated as identical).

I'm genuinely just lost at this part. It requires a city as an input while the procedure as far as I know can only take in a customer name. What should I be changing with my procedure to make it both fulfill the requirements of part 1 and be able to be used in part 2?

Comment: You shouldn't be changing anything in your existing procedure. In your block you'll loop through all customers for a city and call your procedure for every loop iteration.

Comment: You need to write a query to get all the customers from that city and call the procedure for each of them.

Comment: Sorry, but the instructor (or the book) is wrong about a crucial point. *... an anonymous block that* ***would prompt the user ...*** is impossible in PL/SQL, for the simple reason that PL/SQL has no features to allow it to interact with the user. What ***can*** be done is to write a SQL\*Plus script that prompts the user for a city name, saves it in a bind variable, and then calls the anonymous block, passing that value to the block. Think that's what the instructor or the book meant?